# ALTER TABLE and SET values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have added a column t1_num to my table1 and now wish to fill the newly added column. The value for t1_num at each row in table1 should be the number of times the current t1_id showed in table2.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    t1_id
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    t2_id,
    t1_id
);

ALTER TABLE table1
ADD t1_num NUMBER(2) DEFAULT 0;
```

Comment: **current t1_id** - exactly. That's one-time update. Do you plan on maintaining that value afterwards? What happens if another row (with existing T1_ID) is being inserted into TABLE2?

Comment: You should have created a view instead. Or at least use triggers to keep the count values up-to-date. Otherwise you will sooner or later have inconsistent data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `UPDATE` to `set` the values. You may try this.

```
UPDATE table1
SET t1_num = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE table2.t1_id = table1.t1_id
);
```

The `sql` above first creates a temporary table and aggregates the count which is then put into `table1` based on criteria of `table1.id`

You must be careful with the size of each column. Here you have `ADD`ed `t1_num` with size `(2)` (two digits) only. Hope this will meet your requirements as the maximum values it can hold is `99`.